# Is there any way to tell Google to use a particular account for all Google services by default?

Tags: google-account

I typically use 2 Google accounts simultaneously in my browser. So whenever I fire up any Google service like Google Maps or YouTube or Google Search, it uses one of the accounts. The problem is that I don't want that account to be used and no matter how many times I switch the account for these services, they seem to default to same account.

Is there any way to tell Google to use a particular account for **all** Google services by default?

I am not talking about using Google account to sign in to third party websites. I am talking only about Google's own services.

I am using Chrome if anyone is going to suggest client-side solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Log out of both accounts. Then, log in to the Google Account you want as your "default". After that, use "add account" to log yourself in to the second account.

Google should use the first account you logged in as a default whenever you visit one of their apps.

You might need to clear some browser caches to be sure you sign into the accounts in the right order.

Comment: Yeah this actually works. Thanks.